# Confirmar Aspect Ratio de uma imagem para disparar função

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um sistema de upload de imagens em Php e quando as imagens são postadas, criam miniaturas. Hoje, essas miniaturas quando são clicadas chamam uma função jquery para exibir ela em um modal.

Preciso confirmar se essa imagem tem a proporção de 2 para 1 (por exemplo 2000 x 1000px. Mas não posso escolher pelo tamanho, só pela proporção) e se sim, abrir uma outra função, diferente da atual que abre qualquer tamanho.

Ficarei muito agradecido se alguém puder me dar uma luz nisso.

Comment: inclua o código que você já desenvolveu em sua pergunta.

Comment: o código que gera a thumbnail não tem a pista? porque é lá que a imagem é manipulada, certo

Comment: Tentei colar o código mas excede os caracteres na mensagem 600 digitos, há alguma forma de postar código sem essa limitação aqui?

Comment: Coloca apenas o código relacionado, não precisa colocar tudo.

Comment: if ($setUp->getConfig('thumbnails') == true) : ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadImg(thislink, thislinkencoded, thisname, thisID){
        $(".vfm-zoom").html("<i class=\"fa fa-refresh fa-spin\"></i><img class=\"preimg\" src=\"vfm-thumb.php?thumb="+ thislink +"&y=1\" \/>");
        $("#zoomview").data('id', thisID);
        $("#zoomview .thumbtitle").val(thisname);
        var firstImg = $('.preimg');
        firstImg.css('display','none');
        $("#zoomview").modal();

Comment: Acho que não sei postar código aqui ainda,rs Foi mal, minha primeira duvida aqui

Answer (score 0):

Você acha a proporção dividindo a *largura / altura* (`width/height`). Se o resultado for 2, então ela tem a proporção de 2:1. Exemplo:

```js
$("img").click(function(){
   var wd = $(this).width(); // pega largura da imagem
   var hg = $(this).height(); // pega altura da imagem
   var prop = wd/hg; // pega a proporção
   
   console.clear(); // limpa o console (só para exemplo, não inclua isso no seu código)
   
   if(prop == 2){
      outraFuncao(); // chama outra função se for 2:1
   }else{
      console.log("Imagem NÃO tem proporção de 2:1");
   }
});

function outraFuncao(){
   console.log("Imagem tem proporção de 2:1");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Clique nas imagens:
<br>
630x354
<br>
<img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" width="200">
<br><br>
200x100
<br>
<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/1/1c/Marge_procurando_homer_luneta_farol.jpg/revision/latest/window-crop/width/200/x-offset/0/y-offset/48/window-width/650/window-height/325?cb=20170128200714&path-prefix=pt" width="200">
```

Comment: Muitissimo obrigado dvd! Vou testar sua solução!

Comment: Se a imagem for 2:1 vc não quer abrir a modal?

Comment: Na verdade abrir um outro modal diferente (com outro js) do padrão se tiver essa proporção de imagem

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma função assim:

```
$url= "img/imagem.gif"; //url da imagem 

function proporcao($url){

   $tam= getimagesize($url);

   //width = tam[0] / height = tam[1]

   //Retorna se largura = dobro da altura
   return ($tam[0] == ($tam[1]*2));
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Temistocles! Vou testar!

Comment: Por nada, se puder dizer se funcionou ficarei agradecido